# Is trivial topology seperable?

Tags: general-topology, separable-spaces

> $(X,\mathcal T)$ is a t.s.
>
> $\mathcal T                                                                                                                    = \{X,\emptyset\}$

How can we say space is seperable?

Comment: If $X=\emptyset$ then $X$ is countable and dense in $X$. If $X\neq\emptyset$ then $\{a\}$ for $a\in X$ is dense in $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes trivial topology is seperable. We can say a topological space is seperable if and only if there exists at least one countable dense subset of $X$

If we consider singletons,

$\overline {\{x\}} = X$ and we know that singletons are countable thus trivial topology is seperable.

Besides any non-empty subset of $X$ is dense too

Answer (score 0):

Any non-empty subset of $X$ is dense.